# Почему Drawable is null?

Tags: android, java

Я пытаюсь подгрузить Drawable из ресурса. В папке values лежит файл atts.xml, который содержит

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="keyBackground" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

В папке laoyout лежит файл custom_input.xml

```
<com.example.android.softkeyboard.CustomView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
        />
```

В папках drawable-xxx лежит изображение key_background.png. Когда View создается, снаружи вызывается код

```
@Override public View onCreateInputView() {
    mInputView = (CustomView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_input, null);

    // ...

    return mInputView;
}
```

А внутри самого View:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);

LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Drawable mKeyBackground = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomView_keyBackground);
```

---

И вот здесь проблема: mKeyBackground - null. Почему так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у TypedArray getDrawable должен браться по индексу атрибута. По id ресурса Drawable берется у Resources.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getDrawable(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getDrawable(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)

Comment: т.е. у вас должно быть Drawable mKeyBackground = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomView_keyBackground);

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал так:

    Drawable mKeyBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.key_background);